# ASP.NET MVC view engine performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, viewengine

I'm developing high load solution with final version of asp.net mvc. 
Recently our team noticed, that most of the time that takes a server to response to client is devoted to page rendering. Simple time-schedule looks like this:

```
Page start   - 1.8608363s
Render module 1140/Modules/Owners start      - 1.86859s
Render module 1140/Modules/Owners Complete   - 1.9081751s
Render module 829/Modules/Links start    - 1.9081788s
Render module 829/Modules/Links Complete     - 2.3380648s
Render module 1036/Modules/Advertisement start   - 2.3459101s
Render module 1036/Modules/Advertisement Complete    - 2.3482298s
Render module 1110/Modules/Goodies start     - 2.3482322s
Render module 1110/Modules/Goodies Complete      - 2.6300744s
Render module 1004/Modules/TopicLinks start      - 2.6300784s
Render module 1004/Modules/TopicLinks Complete   - 3.8852529s
Render module 1048/Modules/News start    - 3.8927697s
Render module 1048/Modules/News Complete     - 4.4958795s
Render module 1128/Modules/SuggestedLinks start      - 4.4958832s
Render module 1128/Modules/SuggestedLinks Complete   - 4.5704227s
Page end     - 4.5711193s
TopicMainMenuPages start     - 4.5717661s
TopicMainMenuPages End   - 4.571974s
Render Finished      - 4.6185852s
```

What could be a reason for such a slow rendering? Is that for oftentimes using of partial render during single request?

Comment: @Daniel is spot on.  Even in MVC 3 in release mode Render partial is slow.  I was curious why dynamically rendering the default mvc web app home page took almost 200ms, I googled and found this post.    After reading this post I deleted the Html.RenderPartial calls from the master template and render times dropped to 2ms even in Debug Mode.  For Dynamic pages that don't cache well that makes Html.RenderPartial a likely suspect when you have performance problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the `compilation debug="false"` in your `web.config` and build your application in Release mode. This will allow the MVC framework to cache the paths that it resolves for your partial views.

See the [article here](http://blog.dynatrace.com/2009/04/22/aspnet-mvc-hidden-performance-problem-with-htmlhelperrenderpartial-functions/) for more info.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. It gave us up to 2 seconds of performance in average. Everything else is up to our BL modules.

Comment: My page was taking 10 sec to load and now it's less than 1 sec!